# How to repeat a list like this in Angular? Especially with a number of preperty name

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngfor

For example,

```
this.cityService.getCityByCountryId(this.defaultUserNationality, 

    1).subscribe(data => {
          this.cities = data;      
        });
```

and in the html file tried to show like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning">{{cities['0'] | json}}</div>
```

Because it's throw an error:

Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
{
  "success": true,
  "remaining_lookups": 9961,
  "0": {
    "id": "4829764",
    "label": "Alabama",
    "value": "4829764",
    "lat": 32.75041,
    "lon": -86.75026,
    "poi_name": "Alabama",
    "parent_id": "6252001",
    "long": -86.75026
  },
  "1": {
    "id": "5879092",
    "label": "Alaska",
    "value": "5879092",
    "lat": 64.00028,
    "lon": -150.00028,
    "poi_name": "Alaska",
    "parent_id": "6252001",
    "long": -150.00028
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "5551752",
    "label": "Arizona",
    "value": "5551752",
    "lat": 34.5003,
    "lon": -111.50098,
    "poi_name": "Arizona",
    "parent_id": "6252001",
    "long": -111.50098
  },
  "3": {
    "id": "4099753",
    "label": "Arkansas",
    "value": "4099753",
    "lat": 34.75037,
    "lon": -92.50044,
    "poi_name": "Arkansas",
    "parent_id": "6252001",
    "long": -92.50044
  }
  "4": {
    "id": "5332921",
    "label": "California",
    "value": "5332921",
    "lat": 37.25022,
    "lon": -119.75126,
    "poi_name": "California",
    "parent_id": "6252001",
    "long": -119.75126
  },
}
```

Comment: we are going to need more code. Especially the part where you assign and use this object,

Comment: when you define the variable define like: "cities:any={}". So at first not give error

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, the `cities` object is undefined. It only gets a value once you fetch the data. To fix this you could set an initial value to the cities object.

```
class Component{
    public cities = {}; //empty cities object by default. 

    this.cityService.getCityByCountryId(this.defaultUserNationality, 1)
        .subscribe(data => { 
            this.cities = data;
        });
}
```

If you want to repeat the list of cities from Angular. You will first have to convert it to an array. Using `Object.keys` could work for this.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are doing is

```
<div class="alert alert-warning">{{cities['0'] | json}}</div>
```

giving the quotes inside the [] you can get the values by just using cities[0]

[image: check this image]

once check this image, and for your repeat of items you can achieve by doing cities[$index].